# how to check if there is same string in between 2 txt and separate it?

Tags: python

Here are my two txt files which I need to compare and I need to separate the list in a according  to the keywords in b.

For example, `df.movie` , hence I want the `'kyle','movie','c_13'` into `df=[]`.

```
a=[['kyle','movie','c_13'],
   ['blair','food','a_29'],
   ['reese','phone','abc_76'],....]

b=[['df.movie'],
   ['ghk.food'],
   ['qwe.phone'],....]

for line_a in a:
    for line_b in b:
            if line_b in line_a:
                print(line_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Emrah is good. I just wanted to add an alternative solution.

```
a=[['kyle','movie','c_13'],
   ['blair','food','a_29'],
   ['reese','phone','abc_76']]

b=['df.movie',
   'ghk.food',
   'qwe.phone']

b2 = [b_.split(".")[1] for b_ in b]

for item in range(len(a)):
    if any(elem in a[item] for elem in b2):
        print(a[item])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to learn Python and you must work more on creating solutions with python lists.

```
seperateds = {}
for b_ in b:
    b_ = b_[0].split(".")
    b_header = b_[0]
    b_string = b_[1]
    for a_ in a:
        if b_string in a_:
            seperateds[b_header] = a_
            break
print(seperateds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to get this. You can try using this

```
x = {}
for i in b:
    y = i[0].split('.')
    for j in a:
        if y[1] in j : x[y[0]]=j

print (x)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
{'df': ['kyle', 'movie', 'c_13'], 'ghk': ['blair', 'food', 'a_29'], 'qwe': ['reese', 'phone', 'abc_76']}
```